# When updating a row in asp.net gridview with datatable bootstrap. The editrow becomes the last row

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I'm having trouble with my datatables(http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) gridview. When pressing the edit button the gridview enters editmode. But the edited row becomes the last row in the gridview confusing the user. Anyone know how to solve this?

My gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView
        ID="gv_cats"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        runat="server" 
        DataKeyNames="ID"
        CssClass="gvv_cats table table-striped table-bordered"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
        OnRowDeleting="gv_cats_RowDeleting"
        OnRowEditing="gv_cats_RowEditing"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_cats_RowCancelingEdit">    
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" />
            .......
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

datatables-jquery constructor:

```
    var table = $(".gvv_cats").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable({
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        stateSave: true
        });

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
```

Edit: I'm also open for work arounds. I'm thinking in the event: gv_cats_RowEditing go to the last page of the gridview. But how do I pass code to the datatables to goto the last page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain if this will work with your setup, but in my case the edited row bubbled up to the *top* of the table. To get the row to "edit in place" I had to disable ordering:

```js
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#GridViewID').dataTable({
      "ordering": false,
      stateSave: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

It's definitely a workaround and not a fix, but fortunately for me user ordering of the columns was not a requirement. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not a 100% solution because now my ordering doesn't work. But it solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

setting "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]]
or any wanted column number solved for me the problem.